# Can't publish "news.reads" action (paradox included!)

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-opengraph

I recently [asked about some issues I encountered while try to get the Open Graph working](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10366509/open-graph-calls-generating-oauth-exception/10366823#10366823). To solve the issue there, I had to create a second action called `read`. However, since Facebook prefers that their default actions be used, I am afraid that when I submit that action, facebook will reject it as it is too similar to their own `news.reads`.

I'd like to *use* `news.reads`, but when I try to make calls to it, I receive an OAuthException error stating that `news.reads` is not submitted, and can only be used by an admin, developer, or tester. Ironically, I am the sole admin, so this should be a non-issue.

If I try to submit `news.reads`, one of the requirements is to make at least one `publish_action` call to that action.

.. except I can't bloody well make that call if the Graph won't let me, can I? ;)

Is this a Graph API bug?

---

**Edit**: [According to this question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8412612/is-the-news-reads-action-on-the-open-graph-available-yet), the `news.reads` call was made public Jan 18th.

Comment: How are you making the api call? What is the url ur posting to.

Comment: `POST` to https://graph.facebook.com/me/news.reads, with payload `article` => `{URL}`

Answer (score 0):

while reading https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendationsbar/

...In order to use Open Graph publishing, the App must enable the "Enhanced Auth Dialog" migration. This can be done from the "Advanced" settings of the "Edit App" page.
have you enabled it?

Comment: Hello Luca, thanks for the comment. Indeed I have, the option was toggled to "on" when I created my app. One of the threads I read actively recommended *disabling* this option, but neither option  changes the end result.